# PHP function On Each Page Causes Redirect Loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I am working with non-profit on an application that was built by someone else earlier this year.  The site needs to be secure, so I worked with their host to get a SSL cert installed.  I understand that updating the .htaccess server file would be easier to perform the redirect, but our engagement ends in about 3 weeks.  It has been difficult getting the requirements fed through the non-profit customer contact to host company.  As an alternative, I would like to have a php based redirect in place just in case.

This is the beginning section on the apps header page included on all pages.  We have 3 test servers with different domains and a production domain.  I have added a condition so the redirect will not occur when running locally.  When I call the function with my condition causes a redirect loop on the test servers (they have SSL certs).  Can someone help with what I can not quite figure out?  Thanks.

Or does any know if the apache .htaccess file can be updated as a customer user with Dreamhost?

```
<?php 

function redirectToHTTPS() {
    if($_SERVER['HTTPS']!="on") {
        $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("Location:$redirect");
    }
}


$serverList = array('localhost', '127.0.0.1');
if(!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $serverList)) {
    redirectToHTTPS();
}

ob_start();
    include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/rmhcOmahaTeam/config/paths.php');
    include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/rmhcOmahaTeam/config/db_connect.php');
?>
```

Comment: I'm sure that dreamhost will allow .htaccess to be used in directories on their host. if not, you can easily contact their support and let them know that you need it. most hosting companies have .htaccess file enabled including godaddy and other hosting companies that are on shared, virtual, dedicated and on virtual dedicated accounts. its a common feature.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
$serverList = array('localhost', '127.0.0.1');
if(!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $serverList)) {
    redirectToHTTPS();
}
```

What this code says is "if the `HTTP_HOST` variable is `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, then redirect to the SSL site". Then, in the `redirectToHTTPS()` function, you're redirecting to the exact same `HTTP_HOST` you were checking against. So, basically, what you are saying is:

```
if (true) {
    redirectToHTTPS();
}
```

You need to be checking the protocol, not the `HTTP_HOST`:

```
define('HTTPS', isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && filter_var($_SERVER['HTTPS'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));
if ( ! HTTPS) {
    redirectToHTTPS();
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your point.  I am trying to identify localhost and not redirect.  The if condition from what I understand is that the if condition will compare host to my array and since it is ooking for NOT in-array then anything that is not a localhost domain should run the redirect function.  the function should then determine is https was used and if so it would not redirect.